# Div background height 100% (cover)

Tags: image, background

How can i set to a div a background image with a full height (as a cover)?

```
 .index-image-content{
 background: ##00aa77;
 background-image: url("../images/zenbg-1.png"), url("../images/zenbg-2.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 color:#fff;
```

}

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Google background-image.

Answer (score 0):

Just add those to your class

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

[source](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work normally

```
.index-image-content{

 background-image: url("../images/zenbg-1.png"), url("../images/zenbg-2.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;

}
```